# Bitstamp API signature in bash

Tags: bash, bitcoin

I'm trying to access balance of Bitstamp account with API.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Bitstamp API credentials
API_KEY="name_of_my_API_key"
API_SECRET="private_API_key"
CUSTOMER_ID="ID_number"

# Build the nonce
NONCE=$(date +%s%N)

# Sign the message
echo -e "${NONCE}\t${CUSTOMER_ID}\t${API_KEY}\t${API_SECRET}"
SIGNATURE=$(echo -n "${NONCE}${CUSTOMER_ID}${API_KEY}" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "${API_SECRET}" | sed 's/^.* //')
echo ${SIGNATURE}
RESULT=$(curl -s -X POST https://www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/account_balances/usd/ \
     -d "key=${API_KEY}" \
     -d "signature=${SIGNATURE}" \
     -d "nonce=${NONCE}")

# Check if the order was successful
STATUS=$(echo ${RESULT} | jq -r '.status')
if [ "${STATUS}" != "success" ]; then
    echo "Error: Order failed - $(echo ${RESULT} | jq -r '.reason')"
fi
BALANCE_AVAILABLE=$(echo ${RESULT} | jq -r '.available')
echo "${BALANCE_AVAILABLE}"
```

... but I'm getting error: "Invalid signature"

Is there any mistake in SIGNATURE construction please?

Comment: [Don't use UPPER case variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Comment: To get some useful hints paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/.

Comment: Please read the tags you use. [tag:bash] specifically says "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here."

Comment: According to https://www.bitstamp.net/api/#api-authentication, your API key is generated in the site, and then you put it in your code.  The page has examples in other languages.  Using these might be easier.

Answer (score 0):

solution: convert final ${SIGNATURE} to upper case:

```
...
SIGNATURE=$(echo -n "${NONCE}${CUSTOMER_ID}${API_KEY}" | \
    openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "${API_SECRET}" | \
    sed 's/^.* //' | \
    tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')
...
```